# SQL join of different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, join, optimization, conditional-statements

I im writing a larger stored procedure where i have to join a table, which contains agreement. However because our structured database have been made in a rarther peculier way i have to join agreement on different conditions in order to get the correct info on all rows. Since not all agreements exist in rel and and not all exists in identity not all rows get joined.

If i split the statement below up and join agreement twice it works. however then i have two sets of agr, which isn't optimal. The statment below seems to be very inefficent. since normally the whole code will run in 5 min but this never get done, not after 50 minuts.

So is there a better way to make this join, where i first join on agr1.agreement_id = rel.agreement_id and if that returns null (no join) then i use agr1.bill_id = idt.identity on the rest.

```
  left JOIN agreement agr1
  on(agr1.agreement_id = rel.agreement_id)
  or(agr1.bill_id = idt.identity)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use two `left join`s and `coalesce()` in the `select`:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(aa.col1, ab.col1) as col1, 
       . . .
from . . . left join
     agreement aa
     on aa.agreement_id = rel.agreement_id left join
     agreement ab
     on ab.bill_id = idt.identity and aa.agreement_id is null
```

Without the `or` condition, the query should be much faster.

Comment: could you please use the correct aliases, for instance "aa.agreement_id" instead of "a.agreement_id" and "aa.agreement_id is not null" instead of "a.agreement_id is not null"? Thanks.

Comment: @Flavian-CalinicStuparu . . . Fixed.

Comment: Tryed this approach and it worked. Code runs in just a couple of minuts :) thx